# Why form values are prototypes?

Tags: angular

Im trying to create an Angular form for a simple login.

Html code :

```
 <img src="./assets/Logo100Legal.png" alt="Logo" class="logoHome">
    <form #login="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(login)">
        <div class="input-group-lg inputStyle form-group" >
            <h5>Nombre de usuario o correo electronico</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg" ngModel>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-group-lg inputStyle form-group">
            <h5>Contraseña</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg" ngModel>
        </div>
        
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg myButton" value="Iniciar Sesion">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
```

TS Code :

```
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }

  submit(login:any){
    console.log(login.value )
  }
 
}
```

All content appears correctly, but when i click on button it returns a `[[prototype]]` value instead of actual values

Comment: you need add property "name" to your inputs, and you need import the FormsModule in your app.module. NOTE: Why version do you are using, I think that you should to have some errors in console about this

Comment: i have angular `15.0.3`, and `FormsModule` is already imported into `app.module.ts`

Comment: and its correct the error is ```main.ts:11 ERROR Error: NG01352: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
    control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

    Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
    Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">````